# Bootstrap 4.6 - List-group list-horizontal and Overflow of column navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Dear users once again need help from stackoverflow.
I'am trying to create navigation responsive menu that changes on mobile screens dynamicly.
First stage is XL ( navigation is on left )
Second is MD ( navigation is on left, but with icons/no-text )
Third SM ( navigaton is on top only icons with wrap )
Something like this:
X,1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10

Here is my example.gif, but as you can see on SM(small devices) list-group-horizontal is overflowing over the border.
Link to Gif : https://ibb.co/zZ2ctM1

[Link2: Example.Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGuYp.gif)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>xProfile</title>
    <link href="https://xkp.ftp.sh/inc/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">         
  <link href="https://xkp.ftp.sh/inc/css/fontawesome/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <link href="https://xkp.ftp.sh/inc/css/datatables/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    
</head>
<body> 

<div class="container-fluid flex-grow-1 py-1"> 
    <div class="card">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column">    
          
          <div class="list-group list-group-flush d-none d-md-block" id="myList">  
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" href="#adm"><span><i class="far fa-gem mr-4 pr-3"></i></span>admn</a>  
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" href="#general"><span><i class="far fa-gem mr-4 pr-3"></i></span>Информация</a>  
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" href="#change-email"><span><i class="fas fa-laptop mr-4 pr-3"></i></span>Промяна на имейл</a> 
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" href="#change-password"><span><i class="fas fa-bomb mr-4 pr-3"></i></span>Промяна на парола</a> 
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" href="#change-details"><span><i class="fas fa-code mr-4 pr-3"></i></span>Промяна на детайли</a> 
            <br> 
             
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" href="#create-new-user"><span><i class="fas fa-cogs mr-4 pr-3"></i></span>Създай акаунт</a> 
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" href="#view-users"><span><i class="fas fa-laptop mr-4 pr-3"></i></span>Всички потребители</a>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" href="#last-regs"><span><i class="fas fa-laptop mr-4 pr-3"></i></span>Последно регистрирани</a>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" href="#last-logins"><span><i class="fas fa-laptop mr-4 pr-3"></i></span>Последно влезли</a>    
          </div>
         
         
          <div class="list-group list-group-flush list-group-horizontal d-flex flex-fill justify-content-center d-xs-block d-sm-block d-md-none " > 
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action  " data-toggle="list" href="#adm">A</a>                
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action  " data-toggle="list" href="#general">1</a>            
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action  " data-toggle="list" href="#change-email">2</a>       
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action  " data-toggle="list" href="#change-password">3</a>    
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action  " data-toggle="list" href="#change-details">4</a> 
            
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action " data-toggle="list" href="#create-new-user">5</a> 
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action  " data-toggle="list" href="#view-users">6</a>     
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action  " data-toggle="list" href="#last-regs">7</a>          
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action  " data-toggle="list" href="#last-logins">8</a>        
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action  " data-toggle="list" href="#">9</a>                   
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action  " data-toggle="list" href="#">10</a>                  
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action  " data-toggle="list" href="#">11</a>   
          </div>
          
          
        </div>
        
         
        <div class="col border border-primary ">
          <div class="tab-content"> 
             
             <div class="tab-pane fade" id="adm"><hr class="border-light m-0">
                <div class="card-body pb-2">
                    
                    
                    <nav>
                      <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                        <a class="nav-link active border border-primary" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true"> <i style="font-size:18px" class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> Последно влезли </a>
                        <a class="nav-link border border-primary border-left-1" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false"> <i class="fas fa-at"></i> Последно регистрирани</a>
                        <a class="nav-link border border-primary border-left-1" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false"> <i class="fas fa-key"></i> Всички потребител </a>
                        <a class="nav-link border border-primary border-left-1" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false"> <i class="fas fa-paint-roller"></i> Добави потребител</a>
                      </div>
                    </nav>
                    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">.1..</div>
                      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">.2..</div>
                      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">..3.</div>
                    </div>
                    
                    
                </div>
            </div> 
             
             
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="general"><hr class="border-light m-0">
                <div class="card-body pb-2">
                    User Info
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="change-email"><hr class="border-light m-0">
                <div class="card-body pb-2">
                    Change Email form
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="change-password"><hr class="border-light m-0">
                <div class="card-body pb-2">
                    Change Password
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="change-details"><hr class="border-light m-0">
                <div class="card-body pb-2">
                    Change user details
                </div>
            </div> 
             
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="create-new-user"><hr class="border-light m-0">
                <div class="card-body pb-2">
                    CrtNewUser Table
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="view-users"><hr class="border-light m-0">
                <div class="card-body pb-2">
                    VwAllusRs Table
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="last-regs"><hr class="border-light m-0">
                <div class="card-body pb-2">
                    LastReguSr Table
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="last-logins"><hr class="border-light m-0">
                 <div class="card-body pb-2">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table id="example2" class="table small table-hover table-border responsive nowrap" width="100%">  
                            <thead class="thead-dark"> 
                            <tr> 
                                <th class="desktop mobile-l mobile-p tablet-p tablet-l" data-priority="-1">ип</th>
                                <th class="desktop mobile-l mobile-p tablet-p tablet-l" data-priority="-1">име</th>
                                <th class="desktop mobile-l mobile-p tablet-p tablet-l" data-priority="-1">имейл</th> 
                                <th class="desktop">дата</th> 
                                <th class="none">№</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead><tbody>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td>192.167.0.1</td> 
                                    <td>asd</td> 
                                    <td>asd@abv.bg</td>  
                                    <td>19-21-12</td> 
                                    <td>231</td>
                                </tr><tr>
                                    <td>192.2.0.1</td> 
                                    <td>zxc</td> 
                                    <td>zxc@abv.bg</td>  
                                    <td>19-21-12</td> 
                                    <td>31</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody></table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
             
        
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
<hr> </div>

<!-- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -->
<!-- Footer --> 
<!-- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -->
<footer class="text-center">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <p>Copyright © Мартин Бориславов Борисов. All rights reserved.</p>
        <p>privacy policy - Политика за поверителност</p>
        <p>terms of service - Условия за ползване</p>
        <p><a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/"><img alt="Creative Commons License" style="border-width:0" src="https://i.creativecommons.org/l/by-nc-sa/4.0/80x15.png" /></a><br />
        This work is licensed under a <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/">Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 4.0 International License</a>.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
<script src="https://xkp.ftp.sh/inc/js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script src="https://xkp.ftp.sh/inc/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>       
<script src="https://xkp.ftp.sh/inc/js/datatables/datatables.min.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi xkp, welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your link to the image is not readable.  Please read this article how to upload images to Stack Overflow:  https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/18/new-image-upload-support/.

Comment: Thanks for tip, link2 added but i needed to convert the gif to pass the 2mb limit

Comment: By the way i found this awesome library on GITHUB https://github.com/localnetwork/bootstrap4-responsive-tabs

And my problem is solved rly nice mobile dropdown(simple,fast) .

My try is so messy i'am sure my html is full of errors and unnesseserry classes.